# mysql: Multiple records merged into a single record

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table of users that has multiple interests, so when I am querying the `userinterest` table it returns the same user with multiple records but different interest. I am trying to figure out how to join those records on duplicate data but keep the unique data. Below I added the sql statements I have tried.

```
SELECT user.FirstName, user.LastName, user.Profilepix, userinterest.UserId, userinterest.InterestId, interest.Interests, interest.PixLoc 
FROM user 
INNER JOIN userinterest 
ON user.UserId = userinterest.UserId 
INNER JOIN interest 
ON userinterest.InterestId = interest.InterestId 
WHERE user.UserId = 'test1112'
```

[image: sql]

```
SELECT user.FirstName, user.LastName, user.Profilepix, userinterest.UserId, GROUP_CONCAT(userinterest.InterestId), interest.Interests, interest.PixLoc 
FROM user 
INNER JOIN userinterest 
ON user.UserId = userinterest.UserId 
INNER JOIN interest 
ON userinterest.InterestId = interest.InterestId 
WHERE user.UserId = 'test1112'
```

[image: sql2]

When I `GROUP_CONCAT` on `InterestId` the `Interests` and `PixLoc` records get truncated. How would I merge them like `InterestId` is?

Comment: It sounds like you may need a `DISTINCT` inside your `GROUP_CONCAT` as `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT userinterest.InterestId)`.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat , 'The result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the group_concat_max_len system variable, which has a default value of 1024. The value can be set higher, although the effective maximum length of the return value is constrained by the value of max_allowed_packet. The syntax to change the value of group_concat_max_len at runtime is as follows, where val is an unsigned integer:'